# How to group list of tuples?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, grouping, python-itertools

*Note*: I know how I can do this of course in an explicit for loop but I am looking for a solution that is a bit more readable.

If possible, I'd like to solve this by using some of the built-in functionalities. Best case scenario is something like

```
result = [ *groupby logic* ]
```

---

Assuming the following list:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

N = 10

my_tuples = list(zip(np.random.choice(list('ABC'), size=N),
                     np.random.choice(range(100), size=N)))
```

where `my_tuples` is

```
[('C', 74),
 ('A', 74),
 ('C', 87),
 ('C', 99),
 ('A', 23),
 ('A', 2),
 ('C', 21),
 ('B', 52),
 ('C', 1),
 ('C', 87)]
```

How can I group the indices (integer value at index 1 of each tuple) by the labels A, B and C using `groupby` from itertools?

If I do something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

#..

[(k,*v) for k, v in dict(groupby(my_tuples, lambda x: x[0])).items()]
```

I see that this delivers the wrong result.

The desired outcome should be

```
{
  'A': [74, 23, 2],
  # ..
}
```

Comment: Below you say you want a one-liner, but here you say you want more readable. Fewer lines doesn't necessarily mean more readable, and in fact often means much less readable if you try to do too much.

Comment: As the guy who provided the `itertools` answer, I entirely agree with @glibdud. Readable often does not mean one-linize. `collections.defaultdict` also has lower complexity.

Comment: @glibdud Well, I totally agree here. But I promise I left behind the phase where I tried to write "cool code" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(*n*) solution, see [@PatrickHaugh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624452/9209546).

Using `itertools.groupby` requires sorting before grouping, incurring O(*n* log *n*) complexity:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sorter = sorted(my_tuples, key=itemgetter(0))
grouper = groupby(sorter, key=itemgetter(0))

res = {k: list(map(itemgetter(1), v)) for k, v in grouper}

print(res)

{'A': [74, 23, 2],
 'B': [52],
 'C': [74, 87, 99, 21, 1, 87]}
```

Comment: Ah, now I see .. +1 for reminding us about time-complexity.

Comment: Nice. However this is 3 lines.

Comment: Nah I like your 3 liner better. It's OP not liking Patrick's solution because it's not a one liner and accepting this.

Comment: @Attersson, Yep, I agree with you, `defaultdict` is better (I upvoted it). But for educational purposes, it's worth understanding how `itertools.groupby` works.

Comment: @Attersson You can get rid of `sorter` and `grouper` (not saying that would look nice but it's not necessary to declare them). Also jpp got it too: I accepted his answer because I was asking about `groupby` and I assume people might end up here looking for `groupby` examples.

Comment: Very well, got it.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is probably not to use `groupby` at all.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in my_tuples:
    d[k].append(v)
```

The reason I wouldn't use `groupby` is because `groupby(iterable)` groups items in `iterable` that are adjacent.  So to get all of the `'C'` values together, you would first have to sort your list.  Unless you have some reason to use `groupby`, it's unnecessary.

Comment: I was actually hoping to find a "simple" one-liner that keeps the code cleaner. I'd prefer a solution where I write `result = [ *groupby* ]`.

Comment: @StefanFalk I suggest you mention that you want the result to be a one-liner in your original question to get better answers next time.

Comment: That was why I was asking about `groupby` specificly but you're right, it was not quite obvious what I am seeking.